# How can I refresh the listview after I delete my draft when it automatically re-presses?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, native

How can i refresh listview after I delete my draft when it automatically back pressed?

```
public void deleteDraft() {
    ((LoaderActivity) getActivity()).getLoader().show();
    ApiHelper.get().itrDeleteDraft(new ItrDeleteDraftApi.Request(userID, projectID, itrRaisedID)).enqueue(new ApiRequest.Callback<ItrDeleteDraftApi.Response>()  {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ItrDeleteDraftApi.Response response) {
            ((LoaderActivity) requireActivity()).getLoader().hide();
            requireActivity().onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String e) {
            ((LoaderActivity) getActivity()).getLoader().hide();
            ErrorManager.promptError(getActivity(), e);
        }
    });
}
```

```
@OnClick(R.id.buttons_itr_delete) public void onDeleteButtonClick(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).setCancelable(false).setTitle("").setMessage(R.string.confirm_delete_itr).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (d,e)->d.dismiss()).setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (d,e)-> {
            itrDetailFragment.deleteDraft();
        }).create().show();
    }
```

It will refresh or else it will disappear in the list

Comment: you need to refresh the list where the draft show.

Comment: as discuss, need to automatically refresh when it return to list.

Comment: When you back to previous screen you can refresh list automatically from onResume() method.

Comment: it wont work sir

Comment: Share some code of your draft activity from where you call that adaptor.